# Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio 2010 from locking Controller files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I need to modify source files while debugging my ASP.NET MVC app. I know about Edit and Continue, but it doesn't really suit me.

Basically all I need is for Visual Studio to stop making controller files "read-only". There is a similar question on SO about this problem, but the solution (unchecking "edit and continue" in Options) doesn't unlock controller files, although it unlocks all others.

Comment: this would be a useful feature.. you can edit compiled code in other IDEs (just need to rebuild/restart to include your changes)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem. Anytime someone else needs to do this I just share my exported Visual Studio settings with them.

A double check of my setup shows that we have Edit and Continue unchecked in 2 places:

1. In Tools --> Options (visual studio)
2. In Web tab of the MVC project properties (last checkbox)

However there may be other settings that make it work.

We definitely do have the ability to edit any C# file (including controllers) while the debugger is attached. However, getting those changes back into the debugger requires a CTRL + SHIFT + F5.

Comment: Well, it's funny actually. Somehow after restarting app (edit and continue unchecked in both places) it stopped locking controller files. Still not happy, because I'm not sure if it will be consistent. Thanks for the pointers though!